# Reordering git branches: rebasing to an earlier branch in a chain pulls in many extra commits

Tags: git

I have the following:

```
master
      \
       branchA -> branchB -> branchC
```

- `branchA` is in code review (rebased to `master`)
- `branchB` is current work (rebased to `branchA`)
- `branchC` adds a small feature unrelated to `branchB` (rebased to `branchB` currently)

I want to change the order to `branchA -> branchC -> branchB`, which is the order I'll submit merge requests to master.

When, on `branchC` I do `rebase branchA` it seems like I'm causing `branchB`'s commits to become part of `branchC`.

I can `rebase -i` to remove them. But I'm clearly doing something wrong here, and I don't really understand what it is I'm doing wrong. What is the correct way to reorder these branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that git can't just *guess* that branchB is something you don't want when you ask to rebase branchC on top of branchA. branchB is part of its history and so git guesses you want it too. There's a special syntax in rebase for this to work: `git rebase --onto branchA branchB branchC`.

---

*Addition:* Copying in the relevant part of the documentation as it was quite helpful:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

```
$ git rebase --onto master server client
```

This basically says, “Take the client branch, figure out the patches since it diverged from the server branch, and replay these patches in the client branch as if it was based directly off the master branch instead.” It’s a bit complex, but the result is pretty cool.

Comment: Using server client makes it a little bit hard to understand. I would rather say `git rebase --onto new-base ignore-history branch-to-rebase`: Rebase revisions that belong to _branch-to-rebase_ that are **not** part of the history of _ignore-history_ onto _new-base_.